# New markers are not shown in PrimeFaces gmap (JSF 2.2)

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces, google-maps-markers, polling

I'm using PrimeFaces 8.0.3. The first time the page loads, the gmap has no markers because the table where I store the coordinates is empty. When a new marker is added, the page refreshes but the map still doesn't show the marker. This problem only happens when I run the application on the server, because when I run it locally, the new marker is shown without problems. The page refreshes every ten seconds to check if there are new rows in the table.

Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=[provided api key]"></script>
<h:form>
    <p:panel>
        <p:gmap center="-0.2727324,-78.5489364" zoom="18" type="ROADMAP" style="width:90%;height:700px" model="#{mapaCtrl.simpleModel}" />
        <p:poll interval="10" listener="#{contadorCtrl.recargarMapa()}" />
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

MapaCtrl:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MapaCtrl implements Serializable
{
    private MapModel simpleModel;

    ...

    public void dibujarMarcadores()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < listaSolicitud.size(); i++)
        {
            LatLng coord = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(listaSolicitud.get(i).getLatitud()), Double.parseDouble(listaSolicitud.get(i).getLongitud()));
            simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord, listaSolicitud.get(i).getDescripcionsolicitud()));
        }
    }
}
```

ContadorCtrl:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MapaCtrl implements Serializable
{
    ...

    public void recargarMapa()
    {
        ...
        
        if(solicitudesActuales != MapaCtrl.solicitudesIniciales)
        {
            ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            try
            {
                ec.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).getRequestURI());
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(ContadorCtrl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I show the new markers in the map?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign an id to your map component, and then update it when polling:

`<p:gmap id="myMap" center="-0.2727324,-78.5489364" zoom="18" type="ROADMAP" style="width:90%;height:700px" model="#{mapaCtrl.simpleModel}" />`

`<p:poll interval="10" listener="#{contadorCtrl.recargarMapa()}" update="myMap"/>`